# FullCalendar load calendars as they become available

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am using fullCalendar to load internal calendars coming from db and external calendars such as google. Does fullCalendar have a way to load internal calendar items first since they would be available immediately and load external calendar times as they become available?

Comment: When you say internal calendars and external calendars do you mean calendar events? or are you loading multiple calendars on one page?

Comment: yes i am multiple calendars on the same page, including google calendar, exchange calendar, and calendar events from a local db.

Comment: As far as I am aware there is no built in function to load the calendars as they become available. I assume it would need to be something you code yourself. All I can suggest is to read the Full Calendar docs for [Google Calendar](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/google_calendar/) if you have not already.

Comment: looking at fullCalendar docs for addEventSource it seems that we should be able to load event items from different sources as they become available i am just not sure how it works. http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/addEventSource/

Comment: For addEventSource you would have your calendar initialised and then just call addEventSource with the options needed to fetch your new data, but addEventSource will not know when to pull the data, you will need to code that part. It accepts an [Array](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_array/), [URL](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/) or [Function](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/) just like normal event fetching. So like `$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', 'event/path.php')` or whatever method you need.